# How to select values from first few text fields with dynamically ordered class name in a jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to find the sum of first few text fields values with dynamically ordered class names in a DOM using jQuery.

For example:

```
    <input type="text" class="abc5">
    <input type="text" class="xyz5">

    <input type="text" class="abc9">
    <input type="text" class="xyz9">

    <input type="text" class="abc4">
    <input type="text" class="xyz4">

    <input type="text" class="abc3">
    <input type="text" class="abc10">
    <input type="text" class="abc2">
```

how to do select the sum of first two text field values with class name starting with abc? Thanks for the help

Comment: What do you mean with "sum" according to text?

Comment: Sum of the values for the text fields @biberman

Comment: A + B = AB? or A + B = C?

Comment: 1 + 2 = 3 @biberman

Comment: then would be `` <input type="number">`` better

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
$('[class^="abc"]').on("input", function() {
  var n = $('[class^="abc"]').map(function() {
    return $(this).val().match(/^\d+$/) ? +$(this).val() : 0
  }).get().reduce((pv, cv) => {
    return pv + (parseFloat(cv) || 0);
  }, 0)
  console.log(n)
});
```

This will get all the values where the value is a number and multiply them.

**Demo**

```js
$('[class^="abc"]').on("input", function() {
  var n = $('[class^="abc"]').map(function() {
    return $(this).val().match(/^\d+$/) ? +$(this).val() : 0
  }).get().reduce((pv, cv) => {
    return pv + (parseFloat(cv) || 0);
  }, 0)
  console.log(n)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="abc5">
<input type="text" class="xyz5">

<input type="text" class="abc9">
<input type="text" class="xyz9">

<input type="text" class="abc4">
<input type="text" class="xyz4">

<input type="text" class="abc3">
<input type="text" class="abc10">
<input type="text" class="abc2">
```

Answer (score -1):

It will get the first two input fields you can do anything in the body of function.

```
count=0;
$("input").each(function () {
    if($(this).attr(class).substr(0,3) == "abc") {
        $(this).val();
    
        count++;
        if(count > 1) {
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: this counts everytime - if the input is empty or if it has a number or a char as value...

Comment: There can be multiple inputs fields in between and I want to select only the text fields starting with a given class name like "abc" here..

Comment: So you want to select all the inputs where class = "abc" and their can be multiple different inputs with different class names right?

Comment: yes. Where class name starts with abc for example @GhazniAli

Comment: Please check the code again I have updated.

Answer (score -1):

Using vanilla JS, it will only get the values from the first 3 (few) inputs as per your question

```js
// Update function runs when initiated then every time an input is updated
// Just outputs the total to innerHTML of #calcTotal
const update = () => {
  total.innerHTML = `Total: ${values.reduce((sum, a) => sum + a, 0)}`
};

const total = document.getElementById('calcTotal')
const holder = document.getElementById('calcInputs');
const inputs = Array.from(holder.children);

// Empty array to update with for lopp below
const values = [];

// For the first 3 items in inputs[]
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  // Push input value into values[]
  values.push(parseFloat(inputs[i].value))
  
  // Event listener updates value in array every time input is changed
  inputs[i].addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    values[i] = parseFloat(inputs[i].value);
    update();
  })
};

update();
```

```css
body { font-family: sans-serif; margin: 0; }
* { box-sizing: border-box }

#calcInputs { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; }
input { margin: 0.5rem; width: calc( (100% / 3) - 1rem ); }

input:nth-of-type(-n+3) {
 color: red;
 font-weight: 900;
}

#calcTotal {
  margin: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<div id="calcInputs">
  <input type="number" class="abc5" value="10">
  <input type="number" class="xyz5"value="25">

  <input type="number" class="abc9" value="7">
  <input type="number" class="xyz9" value="99">

  <input type="number" class="abc4" value="2">
  <input type="number" class="xyz4" value="5">

  <input type="number" class="abc3" value="401">
  <input type="number" class="abc10" value="62">
  <input type="number" class="abc2" value="63">
</div>

<div id="calcTotal">Total</div>
```